# Why did the range change to $(0,4)$ for density of $X^2$ with $[-1,2]$ uniform distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

The question is: Suppose $X$ has uniform $[-1,2]$ distribution. Find the density of $X^2$.

The range is $(0, 4)$, but it's $g(-1) = 1$ and $g(2) = 4$, so I don't get why it's $(0, 4)$

Also, the solution says this:

For (0,1), $\frac{1/3+1/3}{2\sqrt{y}}$

For (1,4), $\frac{1/3+0}{2\sqrt{y}}$

Why is it split at 1, and how come $(0,1)$ is $1/3+1/3$ and (1,4) is $1/3+0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $g$ is $(\min g(x), \max g(x))$, *not* $(g(\min x), g(\max x))$. In other words, while $g(-1)=(-1)^2=1$, $g(0)=0^2=0<1$ is the minimum of $g(x)=x^2$ on the range $(-1,2)$.

The density function is split in two parts for the same reason, $\forall a\in (0,1)\implies a^2\in (0,1), X=a$ and $X=-a$ both map to $X^2=a^2$, which means the density of $X^2$ is doubled on $(0,1)$

Comment: Can I ask a followup question? For this question: Suppose X has uniform distribution on (-1,1). Find the density of $Y=X^2$, the range for Y is still (-1, 1). But there is now way min(g(x)) can be -1. So I'm not sure how that one has that range.

Comment: That range for $Y$ is categorically wrong. Just as you'd expect, the range of $Y$ is $(0,1)$.